# angularjs http get to php json returned, but ng-repeat not showing results

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

Newb to AnjularJS, searches turned up a lot of similar questions, but nothing seems to fit. This prototype is pretty simple, ng-repeat on a table row, but the ng-repeat is showing 5 blank table rows, I'm expecting just one. My sample json  checks out on JSONlint, and I can console.log it just fine.

I've got a simple html template, js, and php app I'm prototyping. code and screen grabs below.

SCREEN GRAB:

[image]

```js
    angular.module('showcontent', [])
    .controller('showcontentController', ['$scope', '$http', function ($scope, $http)
    {
     $http.get('controller.php')
     .then (function(data)
     {
      $scope.showcontents = data;
    
      console.log("\nhttp get returned data :: \n"+JSON.stringify(data));
      console.log("\n\n"+$scope.showcontents.data[0].ticket+"\n");
     });
    }]);
```

```html
    <body ng-app="showcontent">
    <div class="container-fluid">
     <div class="row">
      <div ng-controller="showcontentController">
      <table>
      <thead>
      <tr>
      <th>TICKET</th>
      <th>SHOW</th>
      <th>SEASON</th>
      <th>EPISODE</th>
      <th>PROVIDER</th>
      <th>MISSINGFROM</th>
      <th>FIXAGENTTICKET</th>
      <th>ACTUAL_START</th>
      <th>ACTUAL_END</th>
      <th>STATUS</th>
      <th>ELEMENT</th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      <tr ng-repeat="showcontent in showcontents">
      <td {{ showcontent.ticket }} </td>
      <td {{ showcontent.show }} </td>
      <td {{ showcontent.season }} </td>
      <td {{ showcontent.episode }} </td>
      <td {{ showcontent.provider }} </td>
      <td {{ showcontent.missingfrom }} </td>
      <td {{ showcontent.fixagentticket }} </td>
      <td {{ showcontent.actual_start }} </td>
      <td {{ showcontent.actual_end }} </td>
      <td {{ showcontent.status }} </td>
      <td {{ showcontent.element }} </td>
      </tr>
      </tbody>
      </table>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    </body>
```

PHP CODE(controller.php)

```
<?php

header('Content-Type: application/json');
$vodContent='[{"ticket": "SI999999999","show": "The New Big Show","season": "1","episode": "1","provider": "cable","missingfrom": "AllX1","fixagentticket": "INC999999999","actual_start": "01-NOV-17","actual_end": "","status": "Working","element": "The Big New Show 1000HD"}]';

echo $vodContent;

?>
```

Comment: additionally, check if this should be renamed: `ng-app="showcontent"`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your HTML is not properly formatted. Try closing your `td` tags:

```
<td> {{ showcontent.ticket }} </td>
```

instead of

```
<td {{ showcontent.ticket }} </td>
```

Also, you may need to access the `data` property of your response object:

```
$scope.showcontents = data.data;
```

Comment: ah, good catch. fixed that, but still 5 blank rows. :-/  no doubt something really silly...

Comment: the *"something silly"* is `$scope.showcontents = data;` should be `$scope.showcontents = data.data;`. The response object in `then()` is not the data...the data is a property of that object